# Prevent Catatrophic Backtracking Matching Image Tags PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regular expression which I am using to try and match all image tags in a string that have an src that is not a local reference (i.e beings with "http").

```
<img(.*?)src=[\"\']http(.*?)[\"\'](.*?)\/>
```

I am running into an issue catastrophic backtracking is occurring when the length of my HTML string begins relatively long.

The image tags may have attributes before or after the src, which is why I have a non greedy match all there. Is there a better way to go about writing this to avoid catastrophic backtracking?

Comment: I'd like to direct you to the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Perhaps consider https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php and then iterating over the result instead.

Answer (score 0):

You assumed the image tag closes with a slash:

```
<img(.*?)src=[\"\']http(.*?)[\"\'](.*?)\/>
```

should be

```
<img(.*?)src=[\"\']http(.*?)[\"\'](.*?)\/?>
```

https://regex101.com/r/iWyHeP/1

---

You have not provided any sample HTML so I'm just going to try and improve your regex at face value:

```
<img\s.*?src=('|")https?:\/\/.+?\1[^\/>]*\/?>
```

Explanation

- `<img\s.*?src=` - img tag plus any attributes leading up to `src=`
- `('|")` - single or double quote; put in capture group #1 to reference later
- `https?:\/\/` - `http` or `https` followed by `://`
- `.+?\1` - the rest of the url leading up to the closing quote from capture group #1
- `[^\/>]*` - any more attributes?
- `\/?>` - close img tag

I used the HTML from https://imgur.com/ and you can see my regex takes almost half the steps as yours:

https://regex101.com/r/fHKFKr/1